# I want to know why we use var for all types of data

Tags: javascript

What is difference between declaring variable using var and without var?

```
a=2;
b=2;
if(a==b)//returning false
if(a===b)//returning false

var a=2;
var b=2;
if(a==b)//returning true
if(a===b)//returning true
```

Why?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it

Comment: is that true?https://jsfiddle.net/kzv5b0bd/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it

Comment: The answer to what you've asked is in the linked duplicate. Regarding the behaviour of the code you've shown, there must be more to it than what you've shown, because those first two if conditions will be `true`, not `false`.

Answer (score 3):

Without [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) will declare the variable globally. Using `var` will declare the variable locally in the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

var defines variable globally, Means that variable defined with var can be accessible form any script below it. And without var it cant

Answer (score 0):

We use `var` for all types because since JavaScript has dynamic typing the type can be inferred automatically during run-time.

Now, for the difference between using the var or not, if you're in a function then var will create a local variable, "no var" will look up the scope chain until it finds the variable or hits the global scope at which point it will create it.